# Opting into IE8-mode zooming in a browser control with DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE

Tags: c#, com, internet-explorer-8, webbrowser-control

According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc849094(v=vs.85).aspx#OptInHighDPI you can make your web browser control use IE8-style zooming, rather than the default IE7 zooming.  It says to specify DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE in your implementation of IDocHostUIHandler.GetHostInfo.

I've seen some examples of C# apps that implement IDocHostUIHandler and call ICustomDoc.SetUIHandler in a DocumentCompleted event handler to wire things up, and I've written a little test app along those lines.  My implementation of GetHostInfo is called, but the IE8 zooming doesn't take effect right away.  The only time I've seen it actually happen is after my Windows 7 screen saver turns off after I move the mouse/touch the keyboard.

This makes me think either:

1. DocumentCompleted is not the right event in which to specify this particular flag (i.e. there's an appropriate event that I don't know about)
2. Using SetUIHandler in any browser control event handler will not work (i.e. use the IOleClientSite method alluded to here http://weborama.blogspot.com/2004/10/mshtml-hosting-idochostuihandler.html)

Does anyone have any successful experience with DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it the IOleClientSite way, which triggered IE8-style zooming in the browser control.  However, child windows still opened at 100% zoom, rather than inheriting the control's 125% setting.

We settled on a non-code solution (we, for the browser control anyway), which was to set a couple of registry values:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom]
"ZoomDisabled"=dword:00000001
"ResetTextSizeOnStartup"=dword:00000001
```

These, combined with the fact that we're using the large fonts Windows feature (120 DPI), causes all browser windows and controls to lock at the default 125% zoom.

Some web apps will need updating because IE8 zooming affects the size of all HTML elements (e.g. pictures, style widths and heights), not just fonts like IE6 and 7.